# Copy an object that contains a super class of another object

Tags: java, oop, copy-constructor

I would like to create a copy of an object that contains a super class of another object. In this example I want to make a copy of the `Box` that contains a `Toy`. But all kind of toys can be in the box. What would be the best way to create the copy constructor in `Toy`?

```
class Box {
    Toy toy;
    public Box(Toy toy) {
        this.toy = toy;
    }
    public Box(Box box) {
        this.toy = new Toy(box.getToy());
    }
}
abstract class Toy {
    public Toy(String name) {
        // ...
    }
}   
class Car extends Toy {
    public Car(String name) {
        super(name);
        // ...
    }
}
class Puppet extends Toy {
    public Puppet(String name) {
        super(name);
        // ...
    }
}
```

I don't really have an idea how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `Toy` have an abstract method `copy()` with return type `Toy`. Then you will be forced to override this in `Car` and `Puppet`. In the copy constructor for `Box` you can use `box.getToy().copy()`.

Comment: Why creating a specific method for this ? `Object.clone` has already this semantic

Comment: You could use `clone()`. I prefer to avoid it though because it's a mess (`Cloneable` doesn't have a `clone` method etc etc).

Comment: I think using `Cloneable` is perfectly fine and safe. See the doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html

Comment: `Cloneable` is pretty widely discouraged, e.g. Effective Java Item 11: "If you extend a class that implements `Cloneable`, you have little choice but to implement `clone` method. Otherwise, **you are better off providing an alternative means of object copying**" (emphasis not mine). As there are several 'gotcha's with the `clone` method, I also think a custom copy method is a much better idea. Also, just to add on to the existing answer, with 1.5+ you can use covariant return types, so the implementations can return their own type instead of `Toy`.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the clone method of each `Toy`'s subclass and then :

```
public Box(Box box) {
    this.toy = (Toy) box.getToy().clone();
}
```

Alternatively, if you have a constant number of types of toy, you can use an enumeration instead of a class.

Answer (score 0):

i think this structure can help you to have an idea,in this case we pass an Object toy using Box Constructor to SuperClass(Toy) and in Toy Class we have a Constructor to Accept an Object from Toy Class then it's call getInstance Method for Initialize toy object(just for example).

```
class Box extends Toy
{
  public Box(Toy toy) 
  {
     super(toy);
  }
}
Class Toy
{
   private static Toy toys = new Toy();
   Toy(){}
   Toy(Toy toy)
   {
      toy = Toy.getInstance();
   }
   public static Toy getInstance()
   {
     return toys;
   }
}
```

and either,if you don't want other Classes(sub class) to don't see a specified methods and attributes just make them private,and if you want sub classes haven't access to set and get methods too,make them private only!